# After Maven build jar changes do not show

Tags: java, maven, jar, build

I made some changes to an old Java project and built a new jar out of it successfully using

```
mvn clean eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse install -DskipTests
```

and saved it in my local directory.

However, when I specify its file path (the local directory location) in another project and run it, the changes don't show in the output. Analyzing the produced jar shoewed, that the new changes were not included.

To be clear: I made changes to the pom.xml; specifically, I added `maven-toolchains` as a plugin dependency.

Any solutions?

Comment: Your question is too generic to get any help. Add some more details, add some code.

Comment: I just extracted the jar file and saw that the code changes have not been saved. Is there a way I can edit the files again on JDGUI and then save sources.

Comment: @source That would not be the way to go. If you just changed the jar file, it would be extremely difficult to analyze behaviour if something doesn't go as planned - especially if (at some point in the future) a new jar is built and used which didn't include those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I don't really understand.

1. Why `install`?
2. Why `eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`?

If you only need the generated jar to be but in a non maven managed application, `package` would suffice, your newly packaged jar would be in `target` dir, non need to install it into local repository.

If you are just packaging your project to put it in the classpath of another project `eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` does nothing useful , it will fix the eclipse project settings,but wont change anything in the build.

My advice is just `mvn package` your project get the file from the `target` directory and copy it into the target project classpath.

If (instead) you have changed also dependency in the project you want to export, maybe just using the artifact is not enough (if you did change something in the POM) there are good chances that you need to do something more then just copying a jar.

Comment: Yes, I did make changes in POM.xml of the project I want to export as JAR.

Comment: In this case you should post: pom changes and how you use your artifact in the other project.

Comment: added maven-toolchains plugin dependency